# Why does the type of IndexedBase variable change when used in an expression?

Tags: python, sympy

I automatically generate some expressions containing `Symbol`s and `IndexedBase`s in sympy and want to manipulate these expressions later. For this I need to know if a symbol in an expression is of type  `IndexedBase`.

It seems that `IndexedBase` objects lose their type when used in an expression:

```py
import sympy as sp
a = sp.IndexedBase("a")
print(f"Symbol: {a}, Type: {type(a)}")

expr = 5*a[1]**2
for s in expr.free_symbols:
    print(f"Symbol: {s}, Type: {type(s)}")
```

The output of the above code is

```
Symbol: a, Type: <class 'sympy.tensor.indexed.IndexedBase'>
Symbol: a, Type: <class 'sympy.core.symbol.Symbol'>
```

How can I get the original type of `a` when only the expression is available to me?

**Update:**
I got the above output using sympy version 1.1.1. As pointed out in the comments, the actual output of `expr.free_symbols` when using a more recent version (1.6.1) of sympy also contains `Indexed` objects which can be used for further manipulation.

Comment: Note that `a.free_symbols` and `expr.free_symbols` are the same. The IndexedBase has stored `Symbol('a')` in its `.args`.

Comment: Oh actually I see that `expr.free_symbols` is `{a, a[1]}` so it also has `a[1]`. In any case I'm not sure that this question is well-posed. An arbitrary expression could have many different things in its free symbols. How would you know which of those objects you are interested in?

Comment: Nevermind. I used an old version of sympy (1.1.1) installed through pip which I thought would give me the most recent version. The output I now get using version 1.6.1 is as you wrote and I can use that to identify the indexed objects in my expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import sympy as sp

a = sp.IndexedBase("a")
print('Symbol:', a, 'Type: ', type(a).__name__)

expr = 5*a[1]**2
for s in expr.free_symbols:
    print('Symbol:', s, 'Type: ', type(a).__name__)
```

Comment: The output is 
```Symbol: a, Type: IndexedBase
Symbol: a, Type: Symbol```
So no information gained here.

Comment: What do you want to do then?

Comment: Ideally I want it to return `IndexedBase` when I ask for the type. But any way to get the original type of `a` would be fine.

Comment: `a`  is not the object of `IndexedBase`, it is being assigned valued returned by `sp.IndexedBase()`

Comment: But the first lines in my example initialize `a` as `IndexedBase` and return the correct type. What am I to make of this?

Comment: Where are your those "first lines". Are they in the code you provided?